# Firebase listeners first time invocation takes time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

First time listener firing takes so much time (approx. 40s), subsequent loads takes lesser time (approx. 1s), how can speed up the first time load as well?

I have given,

```
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

on start of the activity.

```
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("");
        ref.keepSynced(true);
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a listener, you need to know that you are trying to read data over the internet. You cannot compare this with an atempt to read a SQLite database, which is stored locally on disk. The speed of getting the data from Firebase servers, depends on the speed of your internet connection and on the ammount of data that you are trying to get. So most likely the reason for waiting so much is one of this. If the reason is the ammount of data, try to optimize your queries or try to get the data in small parts.

If we are speaking abot the first atempt to read a record, it might be slower than the subsequent ones, because it has to initiate the internet connection. I know that Firebase team is trying to improve the performance, but you can't expect 0ms when retrieving data over a network.

According to your comment, I need to tell you a few more things. There is no way to force the retrieval of the data from the cache while you're connected to the server, as you cannot to stop the retrieval of the data from the cache while you are not connected to the server.

Firebase is desinged to retrieve data from the chache when the device is permanently offline or while your application temporarily loses its network connection and you cannot change this behaviour.

**Edit:**

So to get the `FirebaseDatabase` object you need to use the following line of code once:

```
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
```

Then to get a `DatabaseReference`, you need to use the following line.

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
```

I'm sure you'll need to in your activity more then one reference. Let's say you'll use two:

```
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");
DatabaseReference postRef = rootRef.child("post");
```

You can now add a listener for on each one of these references like this:

```
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        //code to get the data
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

And the code the remove the listener is as explained in my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48861350/should-i-actually-remove-the-valueeventlistener)**.

Don't forget, `onDestroy()` is not always called.

As a conclusion, you create a single database connection, use as many references you need, add the listeners accordingly, remove then according to the life-cycle of you activity.

Comment: I am not trying to read data over internet, I have local firebase db, because I have setPersistenceEnabled(true)

Comment: If I move setPersistenceEnabled(true) to an earlier place in the code, do you think it will work fine? My doubt is that is it because the setPersistenceEnabled(true) takes time to work that the listener firing takes time?

Comment: `setPersistenceEnabled(true)` should be placed as the first line in your activity but remember, if you are still connected to server you cannot get data from cache.

Comment: So are you saying that when firebase is connected to server, it will always load data from the server, neither from disk nor from memory.

Comment: Is there any way to force firebase to retrieve data from the cache with the device connected to network?

Comment: No, there is not!

Comment: Then why are the subsequent calls after the first one taking less time?

Comment: Because there is no need to create a new network connection, It was already made first time.

Comment: Between user device and Firebase servers.

Comment: Is the connection specific to a particular firebase path? Or is it common for all the firebase paths?

Comment: It's the same for all.

Comment: When does it get initiated?

Comment: In the moment in which you are calling this line of code: `DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("");` When you are creating an instance of FirebaseDatabase.

Comment: So if call it for a second time by passing a different argument to getReference() it doesnot matter, it is meant to work faster, provided the first time connection has been established.

Comment: You, but you need to get an instance of your FirebaseDatabase class only once. And then just use it across your activity. And yes, once the connection was made and was successfull, a second connection won't take place.

Comment: I am attaching the listeners to different firebase paths, so how can I get instance only once and use the same thing?, ie getReference() argument is different in different context.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks a lot :)

Comment: If I run the same code in emulator, it takes 1sec first time also, any comment on this behaviour?

Comment: Yes, the behavoiur it's the same on both, emulator or real device.

Comment: In real device it takes about 30s, but in emulator, it takes only 1sec

Comment: It's about the internet connection, the performance of your pc. It will never the same value.

Comment: Internet connection is same, how is PC related to emulator? The specs are given separately for the emulator right?

Comment: Because it runs on your computer is related to that particular computer. If your computer works hard your emulator will work too. And the difference could be that half a second that you are talking about.

Comment: There is a difference of 29 secs, emulator takes only 1sec, physical device takes 30sec.

Comment: I understand. There must be something else. Try to test it on other physical device and see how it behavs.

Comment: Even without internet, it takes 30sec to fire.

Comment: If your opinion about internet connection setup time was correct, it should not have taken so long with out internet right.

Comment: Without internet it should take the data from cache which must be instantly. So this is the flow. First create an internet connection (takes a little more time), after that all the following atempts will not take so long. If you go offline, there must be no delay. So if you say that you have a delay even if you are offline there must be something else which is no related to internet connection but my guees is that is related with the physical device itself. And this cannot be detected using only those lines of code that you have added.