# How to fix slow loading time while loading long text in Textview?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have a textview that will load a long text (5.694 characters) from Firebase, and it makes the activity freeze for about 4 seconds until it displays the whole text.

This is my code:

```
root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
parent = root.child("mainland");
parent.child("main").child("name").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        name.setText(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

is there a way to make the loading time faster, or maybe is there a library just like glide for textview or something?

Comment: Use background thread to do fetch data and after getting data assign text to textview.

Comment: @Faisal, and how to write it? can you share the code?

Comment: [Solved] Someone's from facebook suggest me this https://github.com/metalurgus/LongTextView and it's work. thanks!

Comment: cool. have a good day

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48863393/firebase-listeners-first-time-invocation-takes-time)** out.

Comment: Thankyou @AlexMamo, but my problem is not about the internet, it's because of poor performance of my textview for loading a very long text.