# Does Firebase listeners take up huge memory?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Does `Firebase` listeners like this take up huge heap memory?

```
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    }
});
```

At least when the snapshot is taken?

Comment: Currently your question is not really specific. Maybe change it to: "How much heap memory do firebase listeners take up?" And maybe add samples of the data you put the listeners on. Memory use should be different for a listener on a single string or a listener on a complex object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Database client keeps a copy of all data that you're listening to in memory of your app. Once you remove the last listener for a location, as we have already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48861350/should-i-actually-remove-the-valueeventlistener), the data is removed from memory.

When we are speaking about Firebase, everything is about listeners and as a quick response to your question, no, a listener doesn't take huge memory and you can use as many listeners as you want, if remove them correctly.

Using [addListenerForSingleValueEvent()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query) means that:

> Add a listener for a **`single`** change in the data at this location.

So there is no need to remove the listener.

If you have used for example, `ref.keepSynced(true)`, all data at `ref` location would be kept in memory, and kept up to date.

If you `enable persistence`, the client will also persist active and recent data to disk.

Comment: Does ref.keepSynced consume heap memory?

Comment: Yes, because you'll keep all data at that particular location in memory.

Comment: Does snapShot consume heap memory?

Comment: `Java Heap Space` is the location where are placed the new objects that are created. So when creating a new object of the [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot) class you are using heap sapce.

Comment: Does that heap gets deallocated automatically?

Comment: Yes, it does as in case of all new objects creation.

Comment: Is there everything alright?
Can I help you with other informations?

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome! If you think that my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` will take `snapshot` or sync data only once when called, if there is a change in the data of that node and internet connection is available.

`addValueEventListener()` will take snapshot or sync data from node whenever there is a change in data of that node and internet connection is available.