# How to get online/offline state of the opponent user when there is no internet connection using firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on **chat application** using Firebase, i need online, offline and last seen status of the user whom i am chatting with. I will get this status when user is connected to internet, when user doesn't have internet then it won't be updated in Firebase and it still shows online to offline user.

How to update Firebase database instantly when there is no internet connectivity?

Comment: for updating firebase database we have to use on Disconnect() method,It takes few minutes updating data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to update firebase database instantly when there is no internet connectivity?

There is no way in which you can update a Firebase database while you are offline. When there is no internet connectivity on user's device it means that the user cannot reach Firebase servers, with other words no changes will be made on Firbease servers but, if you are using the following line of code:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

It means that you'll be able to query your the database even if you are offline. This is happening because Firebase creates a local copy of your database. Every change that is made while you are offline, will be updated on Firebase servers once you are back online. To be more clear, every client that is using a Firebase database and uses `setPersistenceEnabled(true)` maintains it's own internal (local) version of the database. When data is updated, it is first written to this local version of the database.

There is also a **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50480943/firebase-connection-check-online-offline-status-in-android)** on which I have answered a few minutes ago and I think you might be interested.

Comment: Then how can i know the user i am chatting with is online or offline?

Comment: how whats app or other chat apps track whether another user went offline when there is no internet connectivity.

Comment: As explained in this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50480943/firebase-connection-check-online-offline-status-in-android)**. Change the property of the user from `isOnline: false` to `isOnline: true` once the user regain internet connection and vice versa, right?

Comment: In the exact same way I have explained above.

Comment: I am using same to save online or offline status of the user in firebase database. But as you explained above we cannot update firebase when there is no internet connectivity. So how can i know the user i am chatting with is offline currently. when user is connected to internet it updates "isOnline" as true, when i lost my internet connectivity it remains "isOnline" as true rather than i should update to "false".

Comment: When the user you are chating with becomes offline (you can know it using my answer from that post) the `isOnline` property of that user becomes `false`. So you need to check constantly the state of the user by adding value event listener on that property, right?

Comment: When the user I am chatting with goes offline because of internet connectivity how the firebase database will be updated "isOnline" true to false?

Comment: See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#how-ondisconnect-works).

Comment: UserReference.child("online").onDisconnect().setValue("false"); i did this code still database not updating the value when there is no internet connectio.

Comment: You are using a `String` for false or the `boolean` false? If it is a boolean you should you: `UserReference.child("online").onDisconnect().setValue(false);`.

Comment: I tried both cases but database updated only an only when internet is connected.

Comment: Check again the doc. Should work. [This](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#server-timestamps) is also how you can set a timestamp.

Comment: onDisconnect() method only execute when internet connected. i think its not right way to update database when there is no internet connection.any other solution have you?

Comment: Is the correct way for doing that, as the official documentation says, not me. If doesn't work, it means that you are doing something wrong and unfortunately, there is no other way, as far as I know.

Comment: Read this: `In realtime applications it is often useful to detect when clients connect/disconnect. For example, you may want to mark a user as 'offline' when their client disconnects. Firebase Database clients provide simple primitives that you can use to write to the database when a client disconnects from the database servers. These updates occur whether the client disconnects cleanly or not, so you can rely on them to clean up data even if a connection is dropped or a client crashes. All write operations, including setting, updating, and removing, can be performed upon a disconnection.`

Comment: Is there everything alright?
Can I help you with other informations?

Comment: its working fine we have to update database onDisconnect() but firebase takes few minute updating data.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add timestamp of both users to firebase at regular intervals .. if connection is down the last active time is shown .. so at both sides check the timestamp difference . If it is greater than some value then display as one user is offline .. makes sure both sides uses GMT time as standard