# NullPointerException in inactive fragment

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database

I have 2 different fragments: one with an EventListener that checks for changes in Firebase, this is the code:

```
dbUsers.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            favo_team_view = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.favo_team_textview);

            if(!(user.getTeam() == null)) {
                favo_team_view.setText("Your favourite team is: " + user.getTeam());
            } else {
                favo_team_view.setText("Your favourite team is: " );
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

And another fragment that deletes an entry in the database, and starts an intent to start the SignInActivity (Both fragments are part of the MainActivity) ; this is the code

```
Button deleteUserButton = myView.findViewById(R.id.delete_user);
    deleteUserButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final String uid = auth.getUid();
            final DatabaseReference dbUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(uid);
            auth.getCurrentUser().delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        dbUsers.setValue(null);
                        signOut();

                    }else{
                        displayMessage(getString(R.string.user_deletion_error));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

private void signOut(){
    Intent signOutIntent = new Intent(myView.getContext(), SigninActivity.class);
    startActivity(signOutIntent);
    //finish();
}
```

The code works in that the entry in the DB gets deleted. But my app crashes, and the stacktrace tells me:

Java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.User.getTeam()' on a null object reference
        at com.ChooseTeam$1.onDataChange

Why does it do that? I don't understand why the Listener still checks for data-changes (that fragment is not active/open when I delete the database)

Thank you

PS: realized i can't check a string on == null, just thought I'd give it a shot. Same thing without the if statement ofcourse

Comment: user is null. Check for this before you call its `getTeam` method

Comment: I did this, it works now, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should check if Datasnapshot exists at first like,

```
 if(datasnapshop.exists(){
    //Your codes here
 }
```

You cannot put "==" for comparing Strings in Java, have you tried

```
if(user.getTeam().equals(null) //statement ;
```

And have you unregistered the listener when Fragment pauses (in OnPause event)?

Comment: I checked if auth.getCurrentUser() is null, and that works for me now.
But the listener is in the oncreateview, if I remove it in onPause, I would also have to reattach in onResume ?

Comment: @user3302053 See **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48861350/should-i-actually-remove-the-valueeventlistener/48862873)** how you can attach and deattach the listener.

Comment: @user3302053 you definitely need to reattach it again if you are planning to use it :)

Answer (score 1):

When you add a listener with `dbUsers.addValueEventListener` that listener:

1. Calls your `onDataChanged` with the latest (or cached) value for the node right away.
2. Starts listening for updates to that node on the server, and calls your `onDataChanged` again when there are changes.

It will continue listening until you [remove the listener with `dbUsers.removeEventListener(...)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#detach_listeners).

There are two possible use-cases, each with their own solution.

1. You only need the data once. In this case, simply change your call `addValueEventListener` to `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`, which will automatically unregister the listener after the first call to your `onDataChange`.
2. You need the data to stay up to date, but only while your activity is active. In that case:
   2.1. Keep a reference to your listener when you register it. I.e. `ValueEventListener mUsersListener` and `mUsersListener = new ValueEventListener(...`.
   2.2. Remove the listener in `onStop`, `onPause`, or another relevant lifecycle method with `dbUsers.removeEventListener(mUsersListener)`