# How to make a like function in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

There is an application in it posts. Likes, done as follows:

```
postReference = firebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");   
holder.likeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final DatabaseReference likeReference = postReference.child(listUserId).child("Likes");
        likeReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild(currentUserId)) {
                    likeReference.child(currentUserId).removeValue();
                } else {
                    likeReference.child(currentUserId).setValue("Like");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is that after pressing the button, the record in the database begins to be added and deleted without stopping. How to fix it? My DB:

[my_database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3AA5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
likeReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {}
```

to

```
likeReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {}
```

See [addListenerForSingleValueEvent](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query) official documentation:

> Add a listener for a single change in the data at this location.

Using `addValueEventListener` it means that you are keeping the listener active all the time. To remove the listener, please see my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48861350/should-i-actually-remove-the-valueeventlistener/48862873)**.