# If there is no onStop() method, when should I call stopListening() method?

Tags: android, methods, android-recyclerview

I succeeded in making what I want [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57702409/10907025). But I only called the method startListening() to recyclerAdapter. When should I call the method stopListening()?? Is there any disadvantage if not call the stopListening() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `stopListening()` at `onDetachedFromRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView)` method of `recyclerViewAdapter`.

```
  @Override
   public void onDetachedFromRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
         stopListening();
   }
```