# The data is not showing in the cardview from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm creating an expense tracker, The app has a login page, and after logging in there are three fragments, Dashboard, Income and Expense. Data is being stored in the database from the dashboard fragment, but I'm not able to retrieve the data from the database in a cardview and show them in the income fragment. Please Help, I'm new to Android

Here is the IncomeFragment.java file

```
public class IncomeFragment extends Fragment {

    //Firebase DB
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference mIncomeDatabase;

    //RecyclerView
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /**if (getArguments() != null) {
         //mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
         //mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
         }*/
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View myview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_income, container, false);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        FirebaseUser mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        String uid = mUser.getUid();

        mIncomeDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("IncomeData").child(uid);

        recyclerView = myview.findViewById(R.id.recycler_id_income);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

        layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        return myview;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Data> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Data>()
                .setQuery(mIncomeDatabase, Data.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Data, MyViewHolder>(options) {

            public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.income_recycler_data, parent, false));
            }

            protected void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Data model) {
                holder.setAmmount(model.getAmount());
                holder.setType(model.getType());
                holder.setNote(model.getNote());
                holder.setDate(model.getDate());
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}


class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }

    void setType(String type) {
        TextView mType = mView.findViewById(R.id.type_txt_income);
        mType.setText(type);
    }

    void setNote(String note) {

        TextView mNote = mView.findViewById(R.id.note_txt_income);
        mNote.setText(note);
    }

    void setDate(String date) {
        TextView mDate = mView.findViewById(R.id.date_txt_income);
        mDate.setText(date);
    }

    void setAmmount(int ammount) {
        TextView mAmmount = mView.findViewById(R.id.amount_txt_income);
        String stammount = String.valueOf(ammount);
        mAmmount.setText(stammount);
    }

}
```

and here is the Data.java

```
package dev.amanraj.expense_tracker.Model;

public class Data {

    private int amount;
    private String type;
    private String note;
    private String id;
    private String date;

    public Data(int amount, String type, String note, String id, String date) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.type = type;
        this.note = note;
        this.id = id;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }

    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

}
```

It's not showing any data in the cardview

I've added Logs in the code and the logs are not showing

```
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                Log.d("Adapter", "onCreateViewHolder");
                return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.income_recycler_data, parent, false));
            }

            protected void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Data model) {
                Log.d("Adapter", "onBindViewHolder");
                holder.setAmmount(model.getAmount());
                holder.setDate(model.getDate());
                holder.setNote(model.getNote());
                holder.setType(model.getType());


            }
```

I'm creating two Childs in the database, as "ExpenseData"(will connect later on to the expense fragment) and as "IncomeData", the "mIncomeDatabase" is connected to "IncomeData"
here's the json

```
{
  "ExpenseData": {
    "tBkG9wB6ILNiNnrl5c8imnX3Ch03": {
      "-NpT9gL6LPB0DY5kznb6": {
        "amount": 500,
        "date": "Jan 31, 2024",
        "id": "-NpT9gL6LPB0DY5kznb6",
        "note": "exnote",
        "type": "extype"
      },
      "-NpTABo6YNBGARNDzAJk": {
        "amount": 20,
        "date": "31-Jan-2024",
        "id": "-NpTABo6YNBGARNDzAJk",
        "note": "phonenote",
        "type": "phoneexpense"
      },
      "-NpTAel71ClSlmDOFZNT": {
        "amount": 101,
        "date": "Jan 31, 2024",
        "id": "-NpTAel71ClSlmDOFZNT",
        "note": "expensenote",
        "type": "expensetype"
      },
      "-NpTrEfhahTOlahpq_Oj": {
        "amount": 6969,
        "date": "Jan 31, 2024",
        "id": "-NpTrEfhahTOlahpq_Oj",
        "note": "check69",
        "type": "check69"
      },
      "-NpXcfymX642t3wAZ8kY": {
        "amount": 60,
        "date": "01-Feb-2024",
        "id": "-NpXcfymX642t3wAZ8kY",
        "note": "Idli Chilli",
        "type": "Food"
      },
      "-NpYCWDKErbCLUWOcNzU": {
        "amount": 300,
        "date": "01-Feb-2024",
        "id": "-NpYCWDKErbCLUWOcNzU",
        "note": "aaj daale gai",
        "type": "Petrol"
      }
    }
  },
  "IncomeData": {
    "aI2gCaEUUPZ7HGORWDIttMy3F3q2": {
      "-NpYCnXfps3Mk-3P9bUs": {
        "amount": 10000,
        "date": "01-Feb-2024",
        "id": "-NpYCnXfps3Mk-3P9bUs",
        "note": "aaj",
        "type": "salary"
      },
      "-NpYE9UIeDB88xnPZ3r2": {
        "amount": 100001,
        "date": "01-Feb-2024",
        "id": "-NpYE9UIeDB88xnPZ3r2",
        "note": "testing",
        "type": "testsalary"
      },
      "-NpYJ2ad8XesxSp-bcWL": {
        "amount": 10101,
        "date": "01-Feb-2024",
        "id": "-NpYJ2ad8XesxSp-bcWL",
        "note": "testnote",
        "type": "testnote"
      }
    },
    "tBkG9wB6ILNiNnrl5c8imnX3Ch03": {
      "-NpT9P5sfXL37veBfLwB": {
        "amount": 1000,
        "date": "Jan 31, 2024",
        "id": "-NpT9P5sfXL37veBfLwB",
        "note": "icnote",
        "type": "ictype"
      },
      "-NpTA8BJPPdeSo-SlL7x": {
        "amount": 420,
        "date": "31-Jan-2024",
        "id": "-NpTA8BJPPdeSo-SlL7x",
        "note": "phonenote",
        "type": "phonetype"
      },
      "-NpTAbSdY9kwHHfCtoQk": {
        "amount": 5500,
        "date": "Jan 31, 2024",
        "id": "-NpTAbSdY9kwHHfCtoQk",
        "note": "incomennote",
        "type": "incometype"
      },
      "-NpTlloj10OFH3A-IA82": {
        "amount": 6969,
        "date": "Jan 31, 2024",
        "id": "-NpTlloj10OFH3A-IA82",
        "note": "note69",
        "type": "check69"
      },
      "-NpU80OgryPX4nNwHCBm": {
        "amount": 10,
        "date": "31-Jan-2024",
        "id": "-NpU80OgryPX4nNwHCBm",
        "note": "aaj khaae hai",
        "type": "samosa"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger, so you'll want to debug the code you shared locally and tell us the outcome. For example, set a breakpoint on the first lines of both `onCreateViewHolder` and `onBindViewHolder`, run in the debugger, and check if it reaches those lines? If so, does the data show up in the variables as you expect there?

Comment: The Android docs have a great page on [debugging your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug) to get you started with, including the section on [working with breakpoints](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#breakPoints) and [inspecting varialbles](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#variablesAndWatches).

Comment: Can you check if your problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55025409/how-to-implement-firebase-recycler-adapter-in-newer-version-of-android-3-1-and-h)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've added Log.d("Adapter", "onCreateViewHolder"); in the onCreateViewHolder and onBindViewHolder and they are not showing in the logcat

Comment: From that, it seems that your code is not getting any data back from the database. That is good progress, as it means all of the layout code and XML is irrelevant to the current problem. --- The next steps would be to: 1) simplify the code in your question to remove the irrelevant parts, 2) include the JSON at `mIncomeDatabase` in your question (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: 3) See if you can read `mIncomeDatabase` without FirebaseUI, to determine whether the problem is in FirebaseUI or in your own code.  The simplest way to read is https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_once