# How to remove an eventListener from "onPostExecute" in an async-task

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-asynctask

How can I remove a ValueEventListener that I am using in "doInBackground" from "onPostExecute" in an "asynchronous task" in java because I am creating an intent in "onPostExecute" and I need to make sure that the listener is removed before I go to another activity?

Comment: To remove a listener from the Firebase Realtime Database, call the relevant [`removeEventListener` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#removeEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)). Beyond that link it's hard to help without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces what you are asking about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48861350/should-i-actually-remove-the-valueeventlistener/48862873)** out.

Answer (score 0):

is this you need?

```
ValueEventListener velOneTime;
DatabaseReference mRefChild;   

     if (velOneTime != null) mRefChild.removeEventListener(velOneTime);
```

use it either onStop or onDestory, depending on your logic.