# Managing the Android back stack and listeners with Firestore for optimizing document reads

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have activity A and activity B in Android.

In activity A there are a `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` and a `FirestoreRecyclerOptions` object, which update in realtime a `RecyclerView`. I start activity B from a button in activity A, but I do not finish Activity A, so that when returning to Activity A I do not need to read again all documents already previously loaded within my recyclerView.

However, if I start a new intent from activity B to activity A, what happens to the Firestore listener in the old Activity A? Is it automatically terminated?

Comment: Instead of describing the code, please add the actual code that you are using.

Comment: I have no specific code, I am describing a scenario - the question is general because I would like to understand how listeners in Firestore work in the case described.

Comment: What is the type of adapter, `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter`?

Comment: Yes, it is the one of interest because my doubt concerns the optimization of realtime listeners, I updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using Query's [addValueEventListener()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#addValueEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)) method, you should remove the listener according to the life-cycle of your activity, as explained in my answer from the following post:

- [Should I actually remove the ValueEventListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48861350/should-i-actually-remove-the-valueeventlistener/48862873)

If you are using the Firebase-UI library, once you start listening for changes in your `onStart()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    firestoreRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
}
```

You also need to stop listening for changes in `onStop()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(firestoreRecyclerAdapter != null) {
        firestoreRecyclerAdapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```