# Check if no documents are returned against a Firebase ui query class

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I am using Firebase-UI with firestore, Now there are chances that no documents are returned against a particular query, so how would I know that?

```
  progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        String city = prefs.getString("selectedCity", "pakistan");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), city, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Query query = db.collection("cities/"+city+"/"+category);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ExploreModel> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ExploreModel>()
                .setQuery(query, ExploreModel.class)
                .build();
        adapter = new ExploreAdapter(options);



        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ExploreAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position) {
                // ExploreModel exploreModel = documentSnapshot.toObject(ExploreModel.class);
                // String id = documentSnapshot.getId();

                String path = documentSnapshot.getReference().getPath();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Position" + position + " path :" + path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent detailActivityIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), SingleItemDetailsActivity.class);
                detailActivityIntent.putExtra("document_path", path);
                detailActivityIntent.putExtra("category",category);
                startActivity(detailActivityIntent);
            }
        });
```

There is an empty screen if no results/ documents are returned, so I want to show a proper empty screen etc.

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: no, No one replied brother

Comment: i guess you got my issue.

Comment: Have you checked **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55832855/managing-the-android-back-stack-and-listeners-with-firestore-for-optimizing-docu/55833440#55833440)** out? If it doesn't work, please also add your database structure and the content of your `ExploreModel` class.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/o8YJBAc

Comment: I just want to know that query has returned no result?

Comment: Together with your database structure (as a screenshot).

Comment: check image above

Comment: this image is of explore model

Comment: That's good, I was talking about a screenshot of your Firestore database structure from your Firebase console.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Cy6LA6V

Comment: Alex buddy reply me?

Comment: I will write you an answer right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You arent't getting anything because the name of your fieds within the model class do **not** match the name of the fields in your database. See `mDescription` vs `description`? Both must be the same.

To solve this, you either change the model class to look like this:

```
public class ExploreModel {
    private String title, description, imageUrl, location;

    public ExploreModel() {}

    public ExploreModel(String title, String description, String imageUrl, String location) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getTitle() { return title; }
    public String getDescription() { return description; }
    public String getImageUrl() { return imageUrl; }
    public String getLocation() { return location; }
}
```

Or you can use annotations:

```
public class ExploreModel {
    private String title, description, imageUrl, location;

    public ExploreModel() {}

    public ExploreModel(String title, String description, String imageUrl, String location) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        this.location = location;
    }

    @PropertyName("mTitle")
    public String getTitle() { return title; }
    @PropertyName("mDescription")
    public String getDescription() { return description; }
    @PropertyName("mImageUrl")
    public String getImageUrl() { return imageUrl; }
    @PropertyName("mLocation")
    public String getLocation() { return location; }
}
```

Comment: my question was there might be no documents available in a particular collection https://imgur.com/a/Cy6LA6V just see this image there are three documents in grocery collection.

Comment: Query query = db.collection("cities/"+city+"/"+category); I want to know if my query object is null

Comment: Your `query` object will never be `null` since you have created a new object of it. If you want to know if it returns some resuls, you need to use a listener or to verify if your `DocumentSnapshot` exists. If you are using your actual naming for your fields, you'll never get any results. So in order to solve that, you first need to change your fields, right?