# Setting data to Firebase Causing My app to restart constantly with no Error in Logical

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have been developing this app since 2019 and I had a released version of it and I was working on an update so there is a new version of the Android Studio came out I have updated Android Studio to `Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 1`
my `kotlin_version = "1.6.10"` and `compileSdk 31` `minSdkVersion 19, targetSdkVersion 31` `android 11`

I was solving some errors at the beginning like `duplicate classes` and stuff until I faced this error with firebase when setting the data to firebase Database or Firestore, before this update my Code was working fine and I didn't change much I just added new functions to the app like `inAppReview`,

what is happening is that whenever I'm setting data or update some existing data in Firebase Databse or Firestore the app restart and leave no error to detect in the Logcat, Logcat will not be cleared it is just wont show error at the moment of restart, and my app will automatically set a new data to the Firestore or Firebase and some times restart when reading values,

In the new update, I have come across errors like `SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed`
and `E/android.vendin: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.` i dont know if it's related but those are showing.

this is a serious problem guys, I have an iOS version same app written in Swift they both share the same functions to write and read to the database I mean same code different Languages connected to the same database there is no errors everything works fine on iOS with the firebase itself, and the same code was working before this update that's mean there's no problem with my code, please if anyone knows anything or came across this kind of situation let me know I need some help, I'm stuck for a week now I have been searching all over the internet Didn't found any answer, if anyone needs a further declaration or sharing some code please let me know

emulator runing R version and the app was tested on a real Device SamsungNote S21

***Note:*** if I Run the app the first time and write to firebase the app will crash or as I mentioned restart.

***Note:*** but if I wrote to firebase and Re-run my app before the app write again or before the crash the app will works fone

project Gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.6.10"
    repositories {
        google()
//        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
//        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven { url 'https://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local/' }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.5"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'

    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()

        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
//        maven { url 'https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox' }
        maven {
            url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
            credentials {
                // Do not change the username below.
                // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username).
                username = 'mapbox'
                // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
                password = "mapboxpass"
            }
        }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "id"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.0.4"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    androidExtensions{
        experimental = true
    }


}


dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation("androidx.room:room-testing:2.4.2")
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1"
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'
    implementation("androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0")
    implementation("androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0")
    // To use the Java-compatible @Experimental API annotation
    implementation("androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.2.0")

    implementation("com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3")
    implementation("com.google.android.play:core-ktx:1.8.1")
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.0.0'

    implementation 'com.github.chintan369:Geo-FireStore-Query:1.1.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.github.imperiumlabs:GeoFirestore-Android:v1.5.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation "com.xwray:groupie:2.8.0"
    implementation "com.xwray:groupie-kotlin-android-extensions:2.8.0"
    implementation "com.xwray:groupie-databinding:2.8.0"
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.3"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.3"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.1.1'

    implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.2.0'){
        exclude group: 'group_name', module: 'module_name'
    }
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:19.0.1'
    implementation "com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-telemetry:6.1.0"
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-locationlayer:0.11.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-annotation-v8:0.7.0'

    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-turf:5.8.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-geojson:5.8.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-services:5.8.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.42.6'
    implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.42.6') {
        transitive = true
    }

    implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
    implementation 'com.github.everhad:AndroidRatingStar:v1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.eyalbira.loadingdots:loading-dots:1.0.2'


}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="28"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        tools:targetApi="m"
        android:protectionLevel="signature|setup|privileged"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">
```

Logcat No Filters - Error

```
2022-03-04 02:57:45.635 11867-20246/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting flex_time=1929000 job_id=-1 period=3859000 source=16 requires_charging=0 preferred_network_type=1 target_class=com.google.android.gms.measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService user_id=0 target_package=com.google.android.gms tag=Measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService.UPLOAD_TASK_TAG task_type=0 required_idleness_state=0 service_kind=0 source_version=201817000 persistence_level=1 preferred_charging_state=1 required_network_type=0 runtime=1646355465605 retry_strategy={"maximum_backoff_seconds":{"3600":0},"initial_backoff_seconds":{"30":0},"retry_policy":{"0":0}} last_runtime=0
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: pending_ops.tag, pending_ops.target_class, pending_ops.target_package, pending_ops.user_id (code 2067 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:938)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:790)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:88)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1701)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1570)
        at apla.a(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):78)
        at apkp.a(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):196)
        at apkp.a(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):20)
        at apkp.a(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):190)
        at apgy.run(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):8)
        at sji.b(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):12)
        at sji.run(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):7)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at spj.run(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):0)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
2022-03-04 02:57:45.716 11867-20246/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting flex_time=1929000 job_id=-1 period=3859000 source=16 requires_charging=0 preferred_network_type=1 target_class=com.google.android.gms.measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService user_id=0 target_package=com.google.android.gms tag=Measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService.UPLOAD_TASK_TAG task_type=0 required_idleness_state=0 service_kind=0 source_version=201817000 persistence_level=1 preferred_charging_state=1 required_network_type=0 runtime=1646355465690 retry_strategy={"maximum_backoff_seconds":{"3600":0},"initial_backoff_seconds":{"30":0},"retry_policy":{"0":0}} last_runtime=0
2022-03-04 02:58:19.783 9181-9181/? E/NotificationService: Muting recently noisy 0|com.qp.delevare_|0|null|10155
2022-03-04 02:58:24.413 9130-24001/? E/FMQ: grantorIdx must be less than 3
2022-03-04 02:58:24.414 9130-24001/? E/FMQ: grantorIdx must be less than 3
2022-03-04 02:58:24.463 423-423/? E/FMQ: grantorIdx must be less than 3
2022-03-04 02:58:24.464 423-423/? E/FMQ: grantorIdx must be less than 3
2022-03-04 02:58:24.633 9130-24001/? E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Inappropriate ioctl for device
2022-03-04 02:58:24.660 9130-24001/? E/FMQ: grantorIdx must be less than 3
2022-03-04 02:58:24.664 423-941/? E/FMQ: grantorIdx must be less than 3
2022-03-04 02:58:24.706 423-24007/? E/FMQ: grantorIdx must be less than 3
2022-03-04 02:58:24.709 9130-9365/? E/FMQ: grantorIdx must be less than 3
2022-03-04 02:58:34.751 11867-19785/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting flex_time=1880000 job_id=-1 period=3761000 source=16 requires_charging=0 preferred_network_type=1 target_class=com.google.android.gms.measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService user_id=0 target_package=com.google.android.gms tag=Measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService.UPLOAD_TASK_TAG task_type=0 required_idleness_state=0 service_kind=0 source_version=201817000 persistence_level=1 preferred_charging_state=1 required_network_type=0 runtime=1646355514744 retry_strategy={"maximum_backoff_seconds":{"3600":0},"initial_backoff_seconds":{"30":0},"retry_policy":{"0":0}} last_runtime=0
2022-03-04 02:58:34.879 11867-20246/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting flex_time=1879000 job_id=-1 period=3760000 source=16 requires_charging=0 preferred_network_type=1 target_class=com.google.android.gms.measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService user_id=0 target_package=com.google.android.gms tag=Measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService.UPLOAD_TASK_TAG task_type=0 required_idleness_state=0 service_kind=0 source_version=201817000 persistence_level=1 preferred_charging_state=1 required_network_type=0 runtime=1646355514866 retry_strategy={"maximum_backoff_seconds":{"3600":0},"initial_backoff_seconds":{"30":0},"retry_policy":{"0":0}} last_runtime=0
2022-03-04 03:11:16.563 9181-9181/? E/RemoteAugmentedAutofillService: Bad service name for flags 1048704: com.google.android.as/com.google.android.apps.miphone.aiai.app.AiAiAugmentedAutofillService
2022-03-04 03:11:25.574 23552-24315/com.qp.delevare_ E/FirebaseCrash: Failed to report uncaught exception
    java.lang.SecurityException: getDataNetworkTypeForSubscriber
        at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2373)
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2357)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2340)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2282)
        at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy.getNetworkTypeForSubscriber(ITelephony.java:8762)
        at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getNetworkType(TelephonyManager.java:3021)
        at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getNetworkType(TelephonyManager.java:2985)
        at aqi.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):164)
        at com.google.firebase.crash.internal.api.FirebaseCrashApiImpl.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):2)
        at com.google.firebase.crash.internal.api.FirebaseCrashApiImpl.reportUncaughtException(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):2)
        at apv.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):10)
        at mi.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):4)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:1043)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.crash.zza.transactAndReadExceptionReturnVoid(Unknown Source:20)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.crash.zzn.zzb(Unknown Source:18)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.crash.zzg.zzd(Unknown Source:13)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.crash.zzc.run(Unknown Source:12)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.crash.zzg.run(Unknown Source:15)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
2022-03-04 03:11:27.463 9181-9211/? E/ActivityTaskManager: Second failure launching com.qp.delevare_/.TabbarActivity, giving up
    android.os.DeadObjectException
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:540)
        at android.app.IApplicationThread$Stub$Proxy.scheduleTransaction(IApplicationThread.java:2504)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction.schedule(ClientTransaction.java:136)
        at com.android.server.wm.ClientLifecycleManager.scheduleTransaction(ClientLifecycleManager.java:47)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStackSupervisor.realStartActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:863)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStackSupervisor.startSpecificActivity(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:971)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStack.resumeTopActivityInnerLocked(ActivityStack.java:1934)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStack.resumeTopActivityUncheckedLocked(ActivityStack.java:1511)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.makeActiveIfNeeded(ActivityRecord.java:4714)
        at com.android.server.wm.EnsureActivitiesVisibleHelper.setActivityVisibilityState(EnsureActivitiesVisibleHelper.java:160)
        at com.android.server.wm.EnsureActivitiesVisibleHelper.lambda$Bbb3nMFa3F8er_OBuKA7-SpeSKo(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.android.server.wm.-$$Lambda$EnsureActivitiesVisibleHelper$Bbb3nMFa3F8er_OBuKA7-SpeSKo.accept(Unknown Source:12)
        at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl.doInvoke(PooledLambdaImpl.java:307)
        at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl.invoke(PooledLambdaImpl.java:201)
        at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.OmniFunction.accept(OmniFunction.java:92)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.forAllActivities(ActivityRecord.java:3625)
        at com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.forAllActivities(WindowContainer.java:1350)
        at com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.forAllActivities(WindowContainer.java:1344)
        at com.android.server.wm.EnsureActivitiesVisibleHelper.process(EnsureActivitiesVisibleHelper.java:104)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStack.ensureActivitiesVisible(ActivityStack.java:1310)
        at com.android.server.wm.TaskDisplayArea.ensureActivitiesVisible(TaskDisplayArea.java:1790)
        at com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.ensureActivitiesVisible(DisplayContent.java:5524)
        at com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.ensureActivitiesVisible(RootWindowContainer.java:2002)
        at com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.ensureActivitiesVisible(RootWindowContainer.java:1984)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStack.completePauseLocked(ActivityStack.java:1244)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.activityPaused(ActivityRecord.java:4937)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord$1.run(ActivityRecord.java:712)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
        at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:44)
2022-03-04 03:11:29.828 12424-12475/? E/MDD: DownloadProgressMonitor: Can't find file group for uri: android://com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/files/sharedminusonemodule/shared/SharedMinusOneData.pb.tmp
2022-03-04 03:11:32.973 9181-10230/? E/system_server: Invalid class loader spec: =UnsupportedClassLoaderContext=
2022-03-04 03:11:32.973 9181-10230/? E/PackageDexUsage: Unsupported context?
2022-03-04 03:11:35.861 11867-16474/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting flex_time=1098000 job_id=-1 period=2198000 source=16 requires_charging=0 preferred_network_type=1 target_class=com.google.android.gms.measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService user_id=0 target_package=com.google.android.gms tag=Measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService.UPLOAD_TASK_TAG task_type=0 required_idleness_state=0 service_kind=0 source_version=201817000 persistence_level=1 preferred_charging_state=1 required_network_type=0 runtime=1646356295857 retry_strategy={"maximum_backoff_seconds":{"3600":0},"initial_backoff_seconds":{"30":0},"retry_policy":{"0":0}} last_runtime=0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: No, it doesn't I'm not that starter I know how to use logcat but there is no errors showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see there are no problems with your dependencies and I think what you have is that you write data to the firebase database after getting some data using ValueEventListener, so even if your activity has destroyed ValueEventListener will still listen in the previous Activity according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63636051/8793968 @ and this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63636048/8793968 @ so it will restart and show no errors

Comment: I will see what I'm doing and give it a try

Comment: that is unfortunately true I didn't know that I did every possible way to detect this error and even I rebuild the whole project from scratch and came across the same result, thanks a lot though