# In Firestore, Firebase provides a ListenerRegistration. Is there a similar functionality in Realtime Database?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database

```
package com.google.firebase.firestore;


public interface ListenerRegistration {
    void remove();
}
```

I've tried to search for some resources. But I haven't found it yet. So please help me

Answer (score 1):

In the Realtime Database, if you need to remove the listener, you have to call [Query#removeEventListener(@NonNull ValueEventListener listener)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#removeEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)) which:

> Removes the specified listener from this location.

Besides that, if it's about Android, don't forget to [remove the listener accordingly to the life-cycle of your activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48861350/should-i-actually-remove-the-valueeventlistener/48862873).

Comment: Hey Naixzzz. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?