# A Service changed Firestore data while the device is offline, will an Activity in the same app using addSnapshotListener receive the change?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

My app has a Service that constantly sends data to Firestore, and an Activity that shows the data.

My design is that, when the device is online, the Activity shows the data in the Firestore, when the device is offline, the Service sends data to the Activity with a local broadcast and sends the data to the Firestore at the same time.

If the change made in Firestore can be received by the Activity when the device is offline, then the local broadcast will be redundant. I can just let Firestore handle both online and offline data display (sending to activity to display).

So my question is, will the Activity receive change in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

If you keep a listener active, yes, you can continue to receive updates. However, this is not a recommended practice. You should [remove the listener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48862873/5246885) according to the life cycle of your activity. In this way, you'll avoid higher bills. Besides that, at some point in time, the Android OS might even stop your app in favor of other apps, or to gain resources. So you cannot rely on that.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. My concern is internet disconnection. For example, the user turn on airplane mode for several hours. To simplify the question, assuming the activity is always in the foreground, so no lifecycle events, will it receive the change made by the service?

Comment: While offline you can continue to use the app. That's why in such a case, when there is no internet connection, everything is written and read from the cache.

Comment: I just want to make sure different components will access the same cache. Does that also mean a different app on the same phone listening to the same document also receive the update? (when the phone has no internet)

Comment: Only if those apps exist within the same Firebase project. Then yes it can listen to the same document. When the phone has no internet everything falls back on the cache.

Comment: Hey Jeffrey. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: I cannot tell for sure. I am busy on other project. I will have to test it when I go back to this one. "All apps on the same device that has permission to access that firestore will be able to receive update locally even without internet" is something I would not believe without testing.

Comment: Sure, give it a try and tell me if it works for you. Keep me posted.